# ASP.Net MVC - Bootstrap Cards that displays horizontally and vertical on any device

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'd like to have the flexbox cards view horizontally and vertically on any screen. I've done it like this and successfully figured out how to display the cards horizontally, but when you try viewing it on a mobile device or smaller screen, the cards remain horizontal. I tried using bootstrap card-deck that didn't help. When i used col d-flex justify-content-center, this allowed the cards to resize but they still don't stack vertically. In other instances i have just used card-deck like here and and its worked fine. Please any suggestions.

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon"type="image/ico" href="/images/favicon/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1" />
    <environment include="Development">
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap//css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
              integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" 
              crossorigin="anonymous"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only"
              asp-fallback-test-property="position"
              asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
              asp-suppress-fallback-integrity="true" >
    </environment>
    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">
                <img src="~/images/employees.png" height="30" width="30" />
            </a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://digitalconsulting.cc/" target="_blank" >Digital Consulting.cc</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home" class="nav-link">List</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-action="create" asp-controller="home" class="nav-link">Create</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tools <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
        {
            @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
}
           <!-- div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"> -->

<div class="card-deck">
    @foreach (var employee in Model)
    {
        <div class="card m-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>@employee.Name</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/images/noimage.jpg"
                 asp-append-version="true" />
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@employee.Id"
                   class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger m-1">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this code on W3 Schools.

Swap out:

```
<div class="card-deck">
    @foreach (var employee in Model)
    {
        <div class="card m-3">
```

With this code:

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    @foreach (var employee in Model)
    {
        <div class="card h-100">
```